# send push message using schedule job to clients

Tags: node.js, cron, google-cloud-messaging, scheduled-tasks

Now I am developing third party server using node.js and GCM.
My app story is that first client choose time.
My server push message on this time.
I tryied using node-schedule but 
I can't find how to cancel the specific schedule.
how to handle schedule job .
e.g. 5 client select 5 pm to push message.
but one client want to change time and the other one client want to cancel pushing message .
how to change  time and cancel specific client's time using schedule job.

Comment: I have the same problem, I found that scheduled tasks are stored in
`var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var scheduledtasks = schedule.scheduledJobs;`
But I don't know how to exploit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give a name to your Schedule task.

So first here's how you schedule a task with node-schedule

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 2);
schedule.scheduleJob('hereisthename', date, function(params)
{

  //Tasks to execute

}.bind(null, params));
```

It will schedule a task that going to be executed in two minutes with the name "hereisthename"

then if you want to cancel it

```
var scheduled = schedule.scheduledJobs;
if (scheduled['hereisthename'] != null)
   scheduled['hereisthename'].cancel();
```

Comment: If the node server is reset. (Turned off and turned on)... does it loose all previous schedules?

Comment: No , I checked this and once node server is reset all scheduled jobs are gone.